# How to update the Ui from background thread - xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I just download the file using the async task it takes more than2 minutes. In between that, I navigate between pages. So The UI thread is not kept in the main thread. When I enter into that page during the mid of download the UI is not updated. Please guide

Mainpage-->Download page-->Download Started-->Go back to main page-->Then Download Page-->Download completed not shown in ui.
I tried to use below code but there is no update in UI.

```
`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{asyncactionToExecute();});`
```

is using message center a better option??

Comment: You might have to add the code for your Page and Also how exactly are you making changes to it for us to help you with this

Comment: You can update the UI in method `onAppearing()` in Download page .